How to assign SwiftUI's eyedropper tool to a button?
SwiftUI provides an eyedropper tool in its ColorPicker() to select a color from the view. To access it you have to open the ColorPicker modal and tap on the eyedropper tool on the top left of the modal. I was wondering if there is a way to assign this eyedropper tool to a button.
Thanks in advance!
